# Passing *args in Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I know how to pass arguments to Robot Framework keyword but when are NOT sure about of arguments, is there any way to do it in the Robot Framework.

In python, we can use `*args` to pass multiple arguments when we are not sure. I am looking for some similar to that in Robot Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [List variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variable-syntax) when defining the arguments in your keyword.

Here is an example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Take Args    arg1    arg2    arg3

*** Keywords ***
Take Args
    [Arguments]    @{args}
    Log    ${args}           # Log as list
    Log Many    @{args}      # Log each item separately
```